# Проверка пользовательского ввода на наличие цифр

Tags: python

Что нужно ввести, чтобы в случае того если пользователь введёт (в оператор input) первым символом цифру, ему выдавало ошибку?

пробовал и так:

```py
text = input("Введите что-нибудь : ")
if text[0] == range(0, 9):
    raise ValueError
```

и так:

```py
text = input("Введите что-нибудь : ")
if text[0].startswith(range(0, 9)):
    raise ValueError
```

(да может это и глупо, но так я тоже пробовал :D)

Comment: Зачем вам вызывать ошибку? для какой цели?

Comment: Для сведения: в `range` можно только наличие чисел проверять, а не символов (пусть даже это символы с числами) и через `in`, а не через `=` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще некуда...

```
if text[0].isdigit():
    raise ValueError
```

Можно ещё так:

```
if text[0] in '1234567890':
    raise ValueError
```

Если очень хочется `range()`:

```
if text[0] in map(str, range(10))
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: Спасибо большое))