# Задача Python c числами

Tags: python

Есть вот такая задача:

Задание: написать игру "Угадай число" , при написании кода выполни следующие условия:

Условия

- программа принимает только целые числа, если число float-Сообщи пользователю и закончи игру!
- выведи число которое загадал пользователь
  если пользователь ввел строку с буквами-Сообщи пользователю и закончи игру!
- если число больше 10-Сообщи пользователю и закончи игру!
- если число меньше 1-Сообщи пользователю и закончи игру
- если число в заданном интервале , но не угадано-Сообщи пользователю, что он "был близко" и закончи игру!
- если пользователь угадал число-поздравь его и закончи игру!

```
from random import randint
user = int(input('Введіть число від 1 до 10 \n:'))
print(f"Число котре ти загадав: {user}")
num = randint(1,10)
num

print(f"Число що випало випадково: {num}")
if user == num:
  print("Вітаю! Ти вгадав число!")
if user > 10:
    print("Число більше заданного формату. Гра закінченна!")
else:
    if user < 1:
        print("Число меньше заданого формату. Гра закінченна!")
    else:
        if user > num:
            print("Твое число більше, ти програв, але був близько!")
        else:
            if user < num:
                print("Твое число меньше, ти програв, але був близько!")
```

Все пункты в данном примере я решил кроме, как сделать что бы при вводе букв или символов програма не падала, а выдавала предупреждение?
Или сделать иначе чем у меня, но главное что бы выполнялись все условия задания!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать что бы програма предупреждала при вводе букв python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1503404/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2-python)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin 404 ответ на ссылку

Comment: @Dmitry, это был предыдущий вопрос автора. он его только что удалил. но тот вопрос был закрыт как дубликат для https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1369125/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Круговорот, блин)(

Comment: кстати, вообще дубликаты живут где-то [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin думаю, что вторая ссылка вводит ТСа в ступор.=)

Comment: @Dmitry, конкретный дубликат выбрал Эникейщик. я же и там и тут привёл лишь список подходящих дубликатов. есть из чего выбрать — вопрос-то мега-популярный. и каждый раз на него отвечают, в основном и не пытаясь указать дубликат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте проверки типа:

```
if user.isdigit(): ...
```

Либо отлавливайте ошибки с помощью:

```
try:
    user = int(input())
except ValueError:
    #  your code
```